# mean, median and standard deviation of a list of numbers in an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, median, standard-deviation

I know this is a pretty common question but I have been trying to correct my code for hours now
thats why I am finally asking it here and yes I have tried to find the solution in google but I still don't understand what is wrong with my code

(btw i am pretty new to bash so I am maybe missing some really silly mistake because of which my program is not working so forgive me for that as a newbie)

Code:

```
#! /bin/bash
# WAP to find the mean, median and standard deviation of a list of numbers in an array.
read -ra a -p "Enter numbers: "
sum=$(
    IFS=+
    echo "$((${a[*]}))"
)
n=${#a[@]}
mean=$(echo "scale=2; $sum/$n" | bc)
echo "mean=$mean"

IFS=$'\n'
b=($(echo "${a[*]}" | sort -n))
IFS=' '
if ((n % 2 == 0)); then
    median=$(echo "scale=2;(${b[(n - 1) / 2]} + ${b[n / 2]})/ 2" | bc)
else
    median=${b[n / 2]}
fi
echo "median=$median"

sd=0
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do
    sd=$(echo "scale=2; $sd + (${a[i]} - $mean)**2" | bc)
done
sd=$(echo "scale=2; sqrt($sd)/$n" | bc)
echo "standard deviation=$sd"
```

Output:
[image]

here you can see I get strange error after median

I hope someone can show me whats wrong with my code

Thank you

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: fwiw, the `bc` exponent operator is `^` (not `**`); making this substituion gets around the `syntax error` issue and generates `standard deviation=.93`; as for whether or not `.93` is the expected result ... I'll leave that up to the OP to decide and/or revisit the math

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks for that info now my code finally works (as i thought because of one silly mistake I wasted so many hours) but yeah standard deviation is coming wrong idk why fml